# Make element immediately draggable during longpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code that makes an element draggable after a long press:

```
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown','.menu-item', function () {
    console.log('mousedown');
    var self = this;
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        $(self).addClass('draggable');
        console.log('draggable');
        $(self).draggable();
    }, 800);
});
```

It technically works, but you have to let up on the mouse and then click to drag.  I would like this to be seamless.  I tried making them all draggable when the DOM loads and then disabling them (`.draggable('disable')`), then reenabling on long-press, but that didn't work either.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/r5du4p6k/4/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the original event on the element after you added the draggable:

```
$(self).draggable().addClass('draggable');
$(self).trigger(event)
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var t;
$(document).on('mousedown','.menu-item', function (event) {
  var self = this;
  if ($(self).hasClass('draggable')) {
    return;
  }
  t = setTimeout(function () {
    $(self).draggable().draggable('enable').addClass('draggable');
    console.log('start drag');
    $(self).trigger(event)
  }, 800);
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function () {
  clearTimeout(t);
  $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable').draggable( 'disable' )
});

$(function() {
  $('#container').append('<div class="menu-item">1</div>')
  $('#container').append('<div class="menu-item">2</div>')
  $('#container').append('<div class="menu-item">3</div>')
  $('#container').append('<div class="menu-item">4</div>')
  $('#container').append('<div class="menu-item">5</div>')
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
.menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.draggable {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#log {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  
</div>

<div id='log'>

</div>
```

> Note that I alse added there `.draggable().draggable('enable')` to reverse the `.draggable('disable')` you had on mouseup, to make sure that after you leave the element you will be able to drag it again (after long-press).

Comment: This causes an endless loop.  How can I avoid that?

Comment: What endless loop? I didn't have any problem with that code... can you please explain?

Comment: I assume it's because `trigger(event)` is triggering the mousedown event again, which starts a new timer, which triggers the event, etc, etc.. no?

Comment: You are correct :) I missed that. Code fixed, you can check now.

Comment: Getting closer, the only issue left is on mouseup I get `Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'`.  I tried switching `.removeClass()` and `.draggable('disable')` but that didn't help.  Might need to be a different question though?

Comment: I really don't see that error on mouseup. Which os/browser you use?

Comment: It's something to do with `helper: 'clone'` I think.